# What aspects to consider when defining attributes or methods in a stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

Below is the definition of a Stateful Widget and its associated state. As we can see, `color` has been defined in `YellowBird` and can be accessed in `_YellowBirdState` via the `widget` object.

My question is with respect to this, **how do we decide where (Widget class or State class) to define the attributes?** For example, `color` could have been defined in `_YellowBirdState` directly. For now, I am deciding this based on whether I have to access the attributes from outside. For example, considering the example below, if I need to access the attribute `color` from outside, then I define it in the Widget class.

```
class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
      const YellowBird({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
      
      var color = 0xFFFFE306;


      @override
      State<YellowBird> createState() => _YellowBirdState();
    }
    
    class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Container(color: Color(widget.color));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason to create the attributes in the widget class is to pass values from outside. In your example you could pass the color dynamically.

```
class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
  Color color;
  
  YellowBird(this.color, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<YellowBird> createState() => _YellowBirdState();
}

class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: widget.color);
  }
}
```

Now you can create your widget with different colors

```
YellowBird(Colors.green)
YellowBird(Colors.red)
```